# Is it possible to train a NN in Keras with features that won't be available for prediction?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm fairly new to this topic as a whole and struggle to wrap my head even the basics of neural networks in general. Not looking for a project plan, appreciate that you probably have better things to do.
Nonetheless, any idea or push in the right direction is appreciated.

Imaging a grey-box model of some kind, thermal network, electrical network, so on, it's desirable to predict returns based on a very few features with an underlying smart model that is trained with a much bigger dataset.

My question would be if it is possible to train a model with features and define mandatory and some sort of good-to-have features for the predictions?

Any tips are appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can train your model like that. But you must feed all the features during prediction. For example, you have 30 mandatory features and 10 optional features. The total is 40. You must feed all the 40 features to get a prediction from your model. Input data shape must be the same always. But we asked for optional features, but why I'm being forced now? well, I will discuss two options.

**Option 1:** set input shape to None. If you set the input shape to None, your model will accept any shape of input. But if you will have to handle some stuff. You can't use the MaxPooling layer. If you really need to use MaxPool, you will need to calculate input, output shape for all the layers only using the mandatory feature shapes(minimum input shape). If you calculate using (mandatory_feature+optional feature), you will end up with an error. Because the shape of the input of the maxpool layer can become too small and can't be reduced. Take care of that stuff and you're good to go.

**Option 2:** I will give you an example. I was using the OpenPose output dataset to classify some movements. OpenPose output = 18 bone key points, 36 features including x and y coordinates. These key points were being extracted from live camera frames. But we can't say all the body parts of a human will be always inside the frame. When someone's legs are outside of the frame, we can't get their legs keypoints. But still, we need to classify. There were a lot of options. We could replace the missing keypoints with 0 or find median/mean of such poses and use that value as key points. We found the best case by analyzing all the data. If you're going with option 2, I will suggest you analyze the data first, then decide how you're going to handle the missing field.

Comment: If it answers your question, please accept this answer. Thank you.